# Is there a difference between "throw MyException()" and "throw (MyException())"?

Tags: c++, exception

I want to know if writing exceptions inbox and out box is changing the behavior or not of a particular program, for example **throw MyException();** and **throw (MyException());**

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class MyException: public exception {
public:
      virtual const char* what() const throw()
      {
         return "Something bad happened";
      }
};
class Test
{
public:
   void goWrong()
   {
      throw (MyException());
   }
};

int main()
{
   Test test;
   try
   {
      test.goWrong();
   }
   catch (MyException &err)
   {
      cout << "The Exception is Executed: " << err.what() << '\n';
   }
   cout << "Still Running" << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The exception-object is copied/moved by the runtime (might be omitted), and is thereafter not const-qualified. One would catch by reference for polymorphic behavior, but would only make it const to guard against mutation, and there's no need.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ok, and I think return and throw are same but using throw make its easier in the debugging time to spot that this is throw and it should return an exception, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I suppose the () could make it throw a reference a la parenthesized return statements. This would cause the thing to be copied a reference, which may be a problem if the original exception temporary it points to is destroyed.

Comment: (I think there should be a medal for a new user whose first question reaches +5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception object is copy-initialised ([`except.throw/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#3.sentence-1)), so it doesn't really matter which one you use; the result is the same.

Copy-initialising would ignore a reference qualifier even if you got one out of this.

We can prove this with some trace output:

```
#include <cstdio>
using std::printf;

struct T
{
    T() { printf("T()\n"); }
    ~T() { printf("~T()\n"); }
    T(const T&) { printf("T(const T&)\n"); }
    T(T&&) { printf("T(T&&)\n"); }
    T& operator=(const T&) { printf("T& operator=(const T&)\n"); return *this; }
    T& operator=(const T&&) { printf("T& operator=(T&&)\n"); return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw T();
    }
    catch (const T&) {}
}
```

Even if you switch from `throw T()` to `throw (T())` the semantics (and output) are exactly the same:

```
T()
T(T&&)
~T()
~T()
```

That is, a temporary `T()` is constructed, then moved into the real exception object (which exists in some magical "safe space"), and ultimately both are destructed.

*Note that, to see this proof, you do have to go back to C++14 (as C++17 doesn't materialise that temporary until the real exception object is needed, per so-called "mandatory elision") and turn off pre-C++17 optional elision (e.g. `-fno-elide-constructors` in GCC).*

If, as some others have claimed, there could be such a thing as "throwing a reference" (which became dangling), you'd only ever see one construction of `T`. In truth, there is no such thing as expressions of reference type, despite the best efforts of `decltype` and `auto` to pretend to you that there are.

**In both cases, the expression we give to `throw` is an rvalue `MyException`.**

The reason we have to be careful with `return` when using a deduced return type (via `decltype(auto)`), is that deduction considers value category. If you have a local variable `int x`, then in `return x` the expression `x` is *xvalue `int`*, so your deduced type will be `int` and everything is fine. If you write `return (x)` instead then the expression is *lvalue `int`*, which results in a deduced type of `int&` and suddenly you have problems. Notice that [neither expression has reference type](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-2) ([a thing which effectively does not exist](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1.sentence-1)). But exactly none of this is relevant in your `throw` scenario anyway, not least of all because your argument is a temporary in the first place.

Comment: It's mean I can safely use whatever I want under/out ?

Comment: @Ali-Baba Yeah but I don't know _why_ you'd want to put the exception object inside parentheses; nobody else does.

Comment: "Copy-initialising would ignore a reference qualifier even if you got one out of this." But if you write `int a; int& b = a;`, and then copy-initialize c like `int& c = b;`, then c copies the reference but not the object it points to. The thing is, there is essentially a decltype in the throw, because the compiler decides the copy semantics from the type given. You're copy-initializing a `MyException&`, not a `MyException`.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 That is not true. The expression `b` there is an lvalue `int`. Reference qualifiers are dropped for all processing. (This is why you'd have to write `std::move` again if you wanted to propagate an rvalue-reference). `c` is bound to `a` there just like `b` is; it's the exact same mechanism. `a` did not get copied either! There is no such thing as "copy-initializing a `MyException&`", because references are an illusion and don't actually exist. The type of the expression passed to `throw`, in each case, is rvalue `MyException`. That's it.

Comment: References are an illusion? Then how come you can't return a reference to a local variable? Yes, `c` is bound to `a` like `b` is. `a` is not copied. There is only one actual `int` object, that is never copied, and in the exception throw case, that solitary object will be destroyed in stack unwinding.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I have seen it on someone's source code where he used this method, I was wondered if it change some behavior, but now its all clear I will use it

Comment: @Anonymous1847: I didn't say the language doesn't have references; I said they're an illusion. We're swiftly getting off-topic here, but this is about how expressions work in C++. There are no expressions of reference type. No such thing exists. A reference type will influence whether the resulting expression is an lvalue or an rvalue, but in this case _it was already going to be an rvalue_. So the two things are literally equivalent and there is no cause for concern.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 _"There is only one actual int object, that is never copied,"_ That is clearly false, otherwise every exception object would get unwound, and no `catch` handlers would ever work. The exception object is in fact copy-initialised from what you give `throw`, per the standard wording I linked to.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings References are not an illusion because an `int&` is stored as a pointer, not as an `int`, and it is copied like a pointer, without copying an `int`. They have functional differences. Second comment: But in the usual case you are not throwing a reference (in the sense that the compiler determines you want your object semantics to be instance semantics, not reference semantics). You are throwing a class instance, which is copied because it is the thrown object. When you add the (), the decltype of the expression becomes a reference type, and the compiler uses reference semant

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Nobody's talking about storage. This is about expressions. The expression given to `throw` as an "argument" _in each case_ is an rvalue `MyException`. That's it. Period. End of story! There is no such thing as "throwing a reference". Don't let the rules of `decltype` and `auto` fool you - they do not tell you the true type of an expression, but instead _adjust it_ to reflect its value category. I don't know how else to explain it, sorry. Cheers.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's not just storage, as I said, it's different copy semantics, which is what matters here.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I'm sorry, you're simply wrong, and I've explained why, but as we're going in circles I think we'll have to agree to disagree. Thanks

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit: perhaps I'm trying to salvage some dignity? Roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Bathsheba Not deliberate rollback. Not sure what it really accomplished tho?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings; I'm just being a pedantic mathematician.

Comment: @Bathsheba lolk - feel free to re-apply it I don't mind ;)

Comment: `decltype(auto)` can be deduced to a reference. `auto` cannot.

Answer (score -5):

I believe it would work like a return statement in C++14 and later, in that parentheses indicate the type to be thrown to be a reference, not the exception instance itself. The reference would be stored and copied and treated like an exception, but the temporary object the reference points to would probably be destroyed in stack unwinding, which may cause problems. It may not cause immediate issues if your exception object is of POD type, since destruction for such an object created on the stack is trivial, but it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you sure? Exception objects generally live in a special reserved place. I think this needs more analysis before coming to a conclusion.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Ah, but the actual exception object is a reference, effectively a pointer. The object it points to is a temporary.

Comment: _"the actual exception object is a reference, effectively a pointer."_ No it isn't. _"The object it points to is a temporary."_ No it isn't.

Comment: The type that is being thrown is a `MyException&`. That is the exception. `MyException&`s will be copied, the `MyException` will not.

Comment: That is simply incorrect. You are fundamentally misunderstanding how expressions work in C++.